# Ignore Redirect In Shared Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In a shared library I have a controller that defines this route.

```
[Route(""), HttpGet]
public RedirectResult DefaultRedirect()
{
  return Redirect("/home/");      
}
```

I have to include this library in a new ASP.Net Core 2.2+React webapp (because I need some of the other classes in it), but I don't want this route to be included.

Is there a way to disable it, so that the user is directed to the root of my React app instead of /home when they enter e.g. http://localhost in their browser?

Comment: If you are unable to do it in code, you could always use an [outbound rewrite rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/modifying-http-response-headers#creating-an-outbound-rule-to-modify-the-http-response-header) to modify the redirect header after you application returns it but before the browser sees it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that and post back. Still interested in a code-based solution though too if anyone knows?

Comment: You could try [IgnoreRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.ignoreroute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). There's a [few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ignoreroute) on it in here that may help.